# Bloomberg Data news Pull in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, bloomberg

Can I pull the CN (individual news) of a security from Bloomberg with its Bloomberg Unique ID (or any other identifier) in Excel using a '=BDS()' or other formula? I can't seem to be able to do this.

In a different circumstance I was using a formula to pull a single field with this function < CN > and I was able to use that.

However, I cant seem to be able to pull the News information using BDS in a similar way.

Some help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you asked the help desk?

Comment: The help desk said: EDFS can facilitate large scale analysis of news data and analytics. However, I am looking for single ticker data.

Comment: The help desk isn't particularly useful. they want all their clients subscribing to more of their ecosystem and products.

Comment: That is not my experience - if there's a way to do it they will generally at least give you some pointers or docs - I suspect you can't access the news programmatically with the standard API.

Comment: "In a different circumstance I was using a formula to pull a single field with this function < CN > and I was able to use that." Can you elaborate?